# JPA JPQL Lock not working

Tags: java, jpa, locking, java-ee-6

First selects all rows with pessimistic lock then updates every row.
Second one does the same thing. I thought second attempt should fail, but it's just working fine. How can I make second attempt fail?

```
List<Developer> devs = em
        .createQuery("select c from Developer c ", Developer.class)
        .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).getResultList();

for (Developer developer : devs) {
    developer.setName("asdf");
}

List<Developer> devs2 = em
        .createQuery("select c from Developer c ", Developer.class)
        .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE).getResultList();

for (Developer developer : devs2) {
    developer.setName("1234");
}
```

Comment: Put the second attempt in a different thread and transaction.

Comment: @Priyesh I put this code in ejb A, then same code in ejb B. In Arquillian test ran those 2 methods in sequence. But it didn't throw any Exception. I thought those 2 would run in different transaction, since it is not in EJB but class with @RunWith(Arquillian.class) annotation

Comment: @DulguunLst what is the type of entity manger you are using in your application?

Comment: The second attempt will only fail if the first transaction is still in play. If the first transaction was committed before the second attempt, it will succeed. You might have to put some kind of wait if you want to replicate the scenario.